# How to make css dynamic for React reusable component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I am developing a React application with SCSS (I am a beginner with SCSS). I am trying to develop reusable components (like with bootstrap, and...).

I begin with "Card", and I want this component to be reusable as possible, as I can reuse it in the same app and in other apps because it will be added to "commun_lib, which is a global repository in GitLab for common use in hole company".

This is what I did:

**Card.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import "./Card.scss";

export function cardStyle(cardWidth, cardHeight) {
  var bodyStyles = document.body.style;
  bodyStyles.setProperty("--card-width", cardWidth+"px");
  bodyStyles.setProperty("--card-height", cardHeight+"px");
}
export default function Card({ title, content }) {
  return (
    <div className="APP_card">
      {title ? (
        <div className="APP_cardHeader">
          <span className="APP_cardTitle">{title}</span>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
      <div className="APP_cardContainer">{content}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Card.scss**

```
//card
$card-bg: #fff;
$card-width: var(--card-width); //280px
$card-height: var(--card-height); //508px
$card-box-shadow: 0px 3px 16px #0a4b6d14;

//card-header
$card-header-height: var(--card-header-height); //33px;
$card-header-bg: var(--card-header-bg);
$card-header-padding: 5px;

//card-title
$card-title-color: #fff;

//border-radius
$border-top-left-radius: 12px;
$border-top-right-radius: 12px;
$border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
$border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;

@mixin border-radius($border-top-left-radius, $border-top-right-radius, $border-bottom-right-radius, $border-bottom-left-radius) {
    border-radius: $border-top-left-radius $border-top-right-radius $border-bottom-right-radius $border-bottom-left-radius;
}

@mixin border($border-color, $border-type, $border-width) {
    border: $border-width $border-type $border-color;
}

.APP_card {
    @include border-radius($border-top-left-radius, $border-top-right-radius, $border-bottom-right-radius, $border-bottom-left-radius );
    @include border(1px, solid, #a5c9ff);
    width: $card-width;
    height: $card-height;
    background-color: $card-bg;
}

.APP_cardHeader {
    @include border-radius($border-top-left-radius, $border-top-right-radius, 0, 0);
    height: $card-header-height;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    padding: $card-header-padding;
    background-color: $card-header-bg;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.APP_cardTitle {
    color: $card-title-color;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.APP_cardContainer {
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

**ActivityCard.jsx**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Card, { cardStyle } from "../../../../shared/components/card/Card";

export default function ActivityCard({ title, indexOfPeriod }) {
....
cardStyle(260, 508);
var cardTitle = (...);
var cardContent = (...);
return <Card title={cardTitle} content={cardContent}></Card>;
}
```

But for every `cardStyle()` call, I should add all CSS properties in order to pass 0 or none for attributes that I don't want to change.

I really do not know if this method can be improved or is there are others methods that are better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in that `cardStyle` would change the width and height of all your cards. You would wanna remove it, and pass `cardWidth` and `cardHeight` to the component directly, with default values to be used when they are not passed.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./Card.scss";

export default function Card({ title, content, cardWidth = 280, cardHeight = 508 }) {
  return (
    <div className="APP_card" style={{ width: cardWidth, height: cardHeight }}>
      {title ? (
        <div className="APP_cardHeader">
          <span className="APP_cardTitle">{title}</span>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
      <div className="APP_cardContainer">{content}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This way, you have a common style applied to all `Card` through SCSS, and custom inline ones scoped to each `Card`.

Comment: i tested what you have proposed and it is working well, but i am wondering that when i will have more attributes it will be confusable. and when i want to setProperty --card-bg for example how i will do it ? and when i want to pass values from jsx to scss for @mixin border-radius, how should i do ?

Comment: If you want to change the bg, do like `cardWidth`. The idea is not to impact other cards by calling setProperty.

Comment: ok i understand, another question please, is there a method to make my code more comprehensive ? like i declare a variable Style wich contains CSS declarations and i add it as props to Card ? like export default function Card({ title, content, style })

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Where style would be an object that contains the SCSS properties for this specific Card.

Comment: thank you @yousoumar for your help. Your proposition solved my problem

Comment: i posted another question ,can you see it ? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75234657/how-to-make-default-style-and-custom-style-of-a-react-reusable-component-working)