# How to make the default style and custom style of a React reusable component work together?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am developing a React application. I am trying to develop reusable components, like Bootstrap, and Antdesign.

I begin with `Card`, and I want this component to be reusable as possible as I can reuse it in the same app and in other apps because it will be added to `commun_lib`, which is a global repository in GitLab for common use in hole company.

This is what I did:

**Card.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import {defaultStyle} from"./Card.style"

export default function Card({ title, content, style = defaultStyle }) {
  return (
    <div style={style.cn_app_card}>
      {title ? (
        <div style={style.cn_app_card_header}>
          <span style={style.cn_app_cardTitle}>{title}</span>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
      <div style={style.cn_app_cardContainer}>{content}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Card.style.js**

```
export var defaultStyle = {
  cn_app_card: {
    width: 500,
    height: 508,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
  },

  cn_app_card_header: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
  },

  cn_app_cardTitle: {
    color: "green",
    lineHeight: "16px",
    fontSize: "13px",
    marginLeft: "10px",
  },

  cn_app_cardContainer: {
    padding: "6px 10px 6px 10px",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    boxSizing: "content-box",
    justifyContent: "center",
  }
};
```

**ActivityCard.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "../../../../shared/components/card/Card";
import { ActivityCard_style } from "./ActivityCard.style";

export default function ActivityCard({ title, indexOfPeriod }) {
....

return <Card title={cardTitle} content={cardContent} style={ActivityCard_style}></Card>;
}
```

**ActivityCard.style.js**

```
export var ActivityCard_style = {
  cn_app_card: {
    width: 200,
    height: 508,
  },

  cn_app_card_header: {
    backgroundColor: "green",
  },

  cn_app_cardTitle: {
    color: "green",
    marginLeft: "10px",
  },

  cn_app_cardContainer: {
    padding: "6px 10px 6px 10px",
  },
};
```

I thought that with this method the `ActivityCard` will inherit the `defaultStyle` from `Card` in addition to his `ActivityCard_style`. But I realize that **only** the classes and attributes which are redeclared in `ActivityCard_style` are working. And like this, I should redefine all classes and attributes, which is not my objective.

What should I do to make this component reusable with minimum code and without redundancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did, `defaultStyle` would be applied only when you didn't pass a style while calling the component. You can do as below to have the expected result.

```js
import React from "react";
import { defaultStyle } from "./Card.style";

export default function Card({ title, content, style = {} }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ ...defaultStyle.cn_app_card, ...style.cn_app_card }}>
      {title ? (
        <div style={{ ...defaultStyle.cn_app_card_header, ...style.cn_app_card_header }}>
          <span style={{ ...defaultStyle.cn_app_cardTitle, ...style.cn_app_cardTitle }}>
            {title}
          </span>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <></>
      )}
      <div style={{ ...defaultStyle.cn_app_cardContainer, ...style.cn_app_cardContainer }}>
        {content}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```