# How to declare CSS classNames with Javascript?

Tags: css

i am declaring css style with js, how to add :hover selector to cn_app_card ?

```
export var card_style = {
  cn_app_card: {
    width: 200,
    height: 508,
  }
};
```

Comment: Which CSS-in-JS library are you using?

Comment: @DBS any! this is how i am writing my code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75234657/how-to-make-the-default-style-and-custom-style-of-a-react-reusable-component-wor)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `&:hover` object with the apropiate stylings:

```
  export var card_style = {
    cn_app_card: {
      width: 200,
      height: 508,
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "red",
        transform: "scale(1.1)",
      },
    },
  };
```